# Change the threshold in "IBM Watson Visual Recognition service custom classifier"

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I created a custom classifier by using this [demo](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/visual-recognition-nodejs). Although, I trained my two class dataset, while testing (trying the classifier) for some images (test images, not presented in training images) I get the error "The score for this image is not above the threshold of 0.5 based on the training data provided". How can I change this threshold in the scripts (javascripts)?

For example, I'm ok to have classification data for images with ranks more than 0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to help you, first, I recommend to you read and to know the [Best practices](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2016/10/watson-visual-recognition-training-best-practices/) from one IBM Professional for getting one better result or accuracy using Visual Recognition.

But, talking about your question, this error is one *condition* inside the Project by IBM Developers, you can simple change the value in the line [#L270](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/visual-recognition-nodejs/blob/master/app.js#L270):

```
//change this value
params.threshold = 0.5; //So the classifers only show images with a confindence level of 0.5 or higher
```

- [Guidelines](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/visual-recognition/customizing.html) for training your Visual Recognition Classifiers.
- [API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/visual-recognition/api/v3/?node#classify_an_image) for Visual Recognition using Node.js

Comment: Thanks. So, I changed the value, and even added "OVERRIDE_CLASSIFIER_ID=my_classifier_id" in .env file to use my custom classifier instead of Watson's. But when I upload an image, nothing happens! Do you know anything about this?

Comment: If my answer helps you, please **mark** the answer following the [Stackoverflow guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). And, in this case, you need to Ask a new question about this new problem. I'll try to help.